# Is there something like azure active directory for google data suit?

Tags: azure-active-directory, looker-studio

I need show reports (from PBI or GDS) to my more than 1000 customers, but with the azure active directory  it its very expensive.

Is there something like azure active directory for google data suit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no,  thry need to register for new account with google account although they can keep using their email,  gmail is not a requirement.